# Constructing PDA for a language

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I want to **prove** or **disprove** that for a given two PDA's (Pushdown Automata) $M_1$ and $M_2$, we can build a PDA $M$ such that

$$L(M) = \{w \in L(M_1) \mid w\text{ contains some string in }L(M_2)\text{ as substring} \}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be possible.

**Hint:** Consider the following two context-free languages over the alphabet $\{ \mathtt{a},\mathtt{b},\mathtt{c},\mathtt{d} \}$:

- $L_1 = \{ \mathtt{a}^n\mathtt{b}^n\mathtt{c}^k\mathtt{d} : n,k \geq 1 \}$;
- $L_2 = \{ \mathtt{a}\mathtt{b}^\ell\mathtt{c}^\ell\mathtt{d} : \ell \geq 1 \}$.

Now identify the language $$L = \{ w \in L_1 : w\text{ has a substring which is in }L_2 \}.$$

(That is, if $\mathtt{a}^n\mathtt{b}^n\mathtt{c}^k\mathtt{d}$ ($n,k \geq 1$) has a substring of the form $\mathtt{a}\mathtt{b}^\ell\mathtt{c}^\ell\mathtt{d}$ ($\ell \geq 1$) what can we say about these integers?)

---

In a bit more generality, suppose that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are two context-free languages over an alphabet $\Sigma$.  Taking a symbol $\mathtt{\#}$ not in $\Sigma$ consider the following context-free languages over $\Sigma \cup \{ \mathtt{\#} \}$:

$$L_1^\prime = \{ \mathtt{\#}u\mathtt{\#} : u \in L_1 \}; \quad L_2^\prime = \{ \mathtt{\#}v\mathtt{\#} : v \in L_2 \}.$$

Now identify the language $$L = \{ w \in L_1^\prime : w\text{ has a substring which is in }L^\prime_2 \}.$$

Comment: You mean we can't prove this, if so, how do we disprove it? Thanks

Comment: @danishjo: I suggest you go through and try to fill in the blanks of my answer above.  The first half gives pretty much an outline of how to show this (provided you know that one particular language is not context-free, and it is in some sense the prototypical non-context-free language).  If you get stuck on specific points, I'm more than willing to help guide you more, but as this is homework, I don't feel it is appropriate to fill in all the blanks.